# Paste the current date into a pre-defined range named within a cell

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have the following formula, `="AI2:AI"&MATCH(REPT("z",255),ILS_IMPORT!A:A)`, which elicits a pre-defined column `AI2:AI3576`. In essence, the formula is providing me with the exact last row number in which data resides within column A. However, there may be a case whereby there are blanks in the end of the data set within column A, but in column B data goes down to `B4000`. The whole premise is to get the last row of data from columns A to AI, so that I can put the current date within the range `AI2:AI3576` or `AI2:AI4000` before importing the data set into the access database.

Two questions (Microsoft Excel 2010):
1) Does anyone have an easier formula that would capture the aforementioned range?
2) Once the range has been established, a simple paste of the current date into that predefined range using VBA would be preferred.  I imagine this being very simple since we would have the range and we have the date Now().

As a caveat, I had this VBA code that will tell the user the row number of the last cell, but they would still have to do the copy and paste function. I would rather not have the user do these steps.

```
Sub LastRowofData()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng1 As Range
Set ws = Sheets("ILS_IMPORT")
Set rng1 = ws.Columns("A:AI").Find("*", ws.[a1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious)
If Not rng1 Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox "The last cell with data is " & rng1.Address(0) & " , therefore copy the current date in AG2 down to the row indicated."
Else
    MsgBox ws.Name & " columns A:AI are empty", vbCritical
End If
End Sub
```

Your thoughts and creativity are much appreciated.

Comment: To be clear, *'the exact last row number in which data resides within column A'* should read *'the exact last row number in which **a text value** resides within column A'*. Finding the last number in a column is different.

Comment: re: *put the current date within the range AI2:AI3576 or AI2:AI4000*. Your code is commented to say that the date should be in AG2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By successively redefining the area you are referring to using [With...End With statements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx), you can accomplish this without assigning a range.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Sheets("ILS_IMPORT")

With ws
    With Intersect(.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion, .Columns("A:AI"))
        If CBool(Application.CountA(.Offset(1, 0))) Then
            With .Offset(1, 34).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1)
                .Cells = Date
            End With
        Else
            MsgBox .Parent.Name & " columns A:AI are empty", vbCritical
        End If
    End With
End With
```

The primary boundaries of the data is first determined using the [Range.CurrentRegion property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196678.aspx), then progressive [Range.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa176182%28v=office.11%29.aspx) and [Range.Offset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840060.aspx) commands shape the range to receive the current date.

Comment: Thank you and you are totally correct in the comments above. I should have re-read for consistency. You obviously deduced quite impressively.  Thanks again.